# Should we implement Serializable interface while making Domain Class in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new in hibernate.I tried some basic CRUD operations using hibernate API.

I created a class Person

```
@Entity
class Person
{
   String name
}
```

I was able to save this class in Database. Till now I was thinking that JPA internally makes this class implement Serializable because only serialization can save the state of an object.But I tried this :

```
Person p=new Person();
boolean bool=p instanceof Serializable;    
sop(bool);   //false
```

Then I created another class Human (found this way of implementation on [Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html))

```
@Entity
class Human implements Serializable
{
    String name    
}

Human h=new Human();
boolean bool=h instanceof Serializable    
sop(bool);  //true
```

Which way we should create our domain classes and how hibernate internally treats these two ways ?

Please help.

Comment: Hibernate doesn't use serialization to persist objects, it binds class properties to fields in a database.

Comment: Why do you think `Serializable` has _anything_ to do with Hibernate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your entities are going to be transfered over a network, to be stored in an HTTP session, or even to be stored in a file on your hard disk then they must implement `Serializable`. Otherwise Hibernate has nothing to do with Serialization, check more here

[Do Hibernate table classes need to be Serializable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726300/do-hibernate-table-classes-need-to-be-serializable)

[Beans serialization in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911472/beans-serialization-in-jsp)